# Calling ashx in virtual app is very slow at first

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, performance, ashx

I have a website and it also has a virtual app inside it. My website is using the ashx's in the virtual app. I am having trouble with the first call of the ashx. The first call usually takes around 20 seconds while the next ones are just 1-2 seconds.

I have Googled and found the suggestion below. I have added it in web.config but did not help.

```
<defaultProxy>
    <proxy bypassonlocal="true" usesystemdefault="false"/>
</defaultProxy>
```

I have also tried to just use URL rewrite. I have moved my pages from the website to the virtual app. So when I browse www.test.com/mypage.html it actually calls the www.test.com/virtualapp/mypage.html

I did not see any improvement with the response time. Any suggestion please? Thank you.

ADDED:
I have set the idle timeout of the app pool to 24 hours. So far, it did not help too. I still have to test tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this might be because the Application Pool in IIS has been recycled and the first request is starting it. In order to reduce this time you could disable Application Pool recycling and if you are running on IIS 7.5 use the [AutoStart feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677260%28v=azure.10%29.aspx).

There could be many reasons why IIS would bring the Application Pool down

- Some period of inactivity (defined in the properties of the application pool)
- Some period (defined in the properties of the application pool)
- Some CPU/Memory thresholds are reached
- Someone modifies the web.config or some file inside the bin folder